# Django: escribir en plantilla los valores de una lista, utilizando sus índices

Tags: python, django

Estoy enviando a una plantilla desde la vista un objeto de la base de datos (model) y una lista. Tanto la lista como el objeto tienen el mismo número de elementos. En la lista añado información de cada elemento que el objeto no tiene, pero que elaboro en la vista porque por mucho que he buscado no encuentro filtros que puedan extraer esa información directamente desde los datos.
En la plantilla recorro el objeto con su for, pero necesito cuando quiero escribir el elemento de la lista que tenga el mismo índice que el for que se está ejecutando no consigo que escriba nada.

```
{% for quiz in finalized %}
<tr>
    <th>{{ quiz.quizfinalized_dateEnd|date:"d/m/Y H:i" }}</th>
    {% with indice=forloop.counter0 %}
        <td>{{ aciertos.indice }}</td>
        <td>{{ errores.indice }}</td>
        <td>{{ errores.indice }}</td>
        <td>{{ quiz.quizfinalized_result }}</td>
    {% endwith %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Si escribo `{{ aciertos.0 }}` o `{{ errores.2 }}` me muestra el valor correctamente, pero cuando utilizo el valor del índice del for en la forma en la que se muestra anteriormente, no muestra nada.

¿Alguien sabría si es posible escribir un elemento de la lista, usando su índice, pero a través de una variable, y no directamente con .0, .1, etcétera?

Comment: si es una lista, es obvio que no tenga llaves solo indices. deberas crear un dict si quieres llaves :v

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución -nada elegante- que puedo aprovechar, ya que los resultados vienen paginados y como mucho se muestran 5 elementos.

Es esta:

```
{% for quiz in finalized %}
<tr>
    <th>{{ quiz.quizfinalized_dateEnd|date:"d/m/Y H:i" }}</th>
    {% with indice=forloop.counter0 %}                            
        <td>{% cycle aciertos.0 aciertos.1 aciertos.2 aciertos.3 aciertos.4 %}</td>
        <td>{% cycle errores.0 errores.1 errores.2 errores.3 errores.4 %}</td>
        <td>{% cycle nocontesta.0 nocontesta.1 nocontesta.2 nocontesta.3 nocontesta.4 %}</td>                            
        <td>{{ quiz.quizfinalized_result }}</td>
    {% endwith %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Funciona como yo quiero, pero entiendo que si en vez de 5 elementos, fueran 10 o 100, esto sería inviable. Dejo abierta la pregunta por si alguien puede aportar alguna solución.

Gracias